# jquery.transit hover not working

Tags: jquery, hover, mouse, scale, transition

I am trying to create a basic hover effect using jquery.transit.

When the cursor hovers over one of my icons, I want that icon to scale up 100%, and then reduce 100% when the cursor moves away.

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('enqbutton').hover(
     function () {$(this).transition({ scale: [2] });, 
     function () {$(this).transition({ scale: [0] });
     }); });
```

`enqbutton` is a div class.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting a class but rather a html element, change your selector to,

```
$('.enqbutton')
```

Also you must enclose functions in curly braces, try to keep your code well formatted so it helps to spot these errors, an example of how I would write it;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.enqbutton').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).transition({ scale: [2] });
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).transition({ scale: [0] });
        }
    ); 
});
```

Doing it like so allows you to easily spot errors that would otherwise be hard to spot saving you hours of finding these errors allowing you more time to code!

Good luck and I hoped this helped!

Comment: You are also missing a function curly brace, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.` to target class in jQuery:

```
$('.enqbutton')
```

as well as you're missing a `}` to close your first function:

```
function () {$(this).transition({ scale: [2] });}, 
------------------------------------------------^ add it here -----
```